# How to open react material date picker without showing date text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui, mui-x

I am using react material (MUI-X) date picker and my requirement os to open date picker on button click.But I do not want to show date text field of date picker, just show calender and select date.
I tried with multiple solutions like custom render text field and slotProps in text field but could not achieve this beahviour. Any idea how to achieve this
I ma using @mui/x-date-picker and its latest version

I tried statis date picker but i want modal kind of behaviour. At very high level...I do not want text field

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to display the date picker, it seems that the [StaticDatePicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/) satisfies your needs, and if you want it to pop up like the other versions you need to incorporate a [Popover](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/)

```
export default function DatePickerPopOver() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(
    null
  );

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Button aria-describedby={id} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Date Picker
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
          <StaticDatePicker defaultValue={dayjs("2022-04-17")} />
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @nginocchio..yes i did the same ...but i want same animation and pop up effect as we get when we use normal datepicker. I want that behaviour

Comment: I did by custom text field approach and it is opening calender. But it is also throwing the error , The anchorEl prop provided to the component is invalid